# How do I give PyCharm Admin permission?

Tags: python, pycharm, admin

Having a hard time reading this excel file. I did some googling and it looked like I needed to give PyCharm admin permission. So I exited out and then "ran as administrator". Still having the same error. Not even sure if that the actual problem or if I'm doing something else wrong.

my code

```
import xlrd

loc = (r"C:\Users\tyler\OneDrive\Documents\GB-NYJ 2002 W17.xlsx")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
print(sheet.cell_value(0, 0))
```

the error

```
C:\Users\tyler\PycharmProjects\NFLModel\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/tyler/PycharmProjects/NFLModel/Carson.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tyler/PycharmProjects/NFLModel/Carson.py", line 10, in <module>
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
  File "C:\Users\tyler\PycharmProjects\NFLModel\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 111, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\tyler\\OneDrive\\Documents\\GB-NYJ 2002 W17.xlsx'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What are the permissions on the file you are trying to access?

Comment: puffin I just want to read the file and print/use the data

Comment: I understand that, I'm asking for the permissions you have for that specific file. If you right click the file, open properties, under the security tab you should see a list of permissions. To read the file you'll need a check mark next to `Read`

Comment: Gotcha all the permissions are checked

Comment: Huh, interesting. There could be some weird corruption or system issue. I might try copying the file somewhere else and attempt to read that new file to see if its a python issue or a system issue.

Comment: saved it to my desktop. .Still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it to work. Unfortunately I'm not 100% sure what exactly the issue was. So I'll just rundown the steps I tool

1. run pycharm with admin permission
2. Set Configuration to the file that's running
3. Create init file

At this point it was still not working

4. Restart computer. Then it worked lol

Someone suggested that Windows could have been running Excel in the background and that was stopping python from accessing the file. Like I said though, can't be 100% that was the sole issue.

Answer (score 1):

make sure your .py is in the PyCharm -->Run-->Edit Configuration

Comment: Hey so I'm new to python. Still figuring this out. I'm on the run/debug configuration. Am I supposed to change the script path?

Comment: what do I change it to?

Comment: set it to C:\Users\tyler\PycharmProjects\NFLModel\Carson.py still not running

Comment: Alternatively, "Create a __init__.py in the outermost part having your main folders of code...run that __init__.py....it fixed for me" as  per the https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003278140-PermissionError-Errno-13-Permission-denied-C-XXXX-windows-10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220251/discussion-between-tyl-er-and-gmanika).